# OLK5F folder in windows

Tags: windows

What is this OLK5F folder in windows?? What does the name stand for?
Can't view it in explorer!

Comment: Full path please...but if you can't see it in Windows Explorer. Then your computer is infected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers it's a temp folder Outlook uses.  `It should be located at C:/Documents and Settings/MyUserName/Local Settings/Temporary Internet Files` as BloodPhilia said.  On some systems it will be named differently.  The OLK will be same, but the last two characters are randomly generated.  Don't worry that you can't see it in Explorer.  It's odd like that.  You can't browse to it unless you enter the full path, and it doesn't show up even if you have hidden files shown.  It's not very useful behavior in my opinion, but it is normal.

Comment: Oh, then "OLK" stands for "Outlook", I guess. Thanks for the response. It doesn't show up in explorer and that was the reason for my curiosity. But appears in the cmd prompt! Weird.

Answer (score 0):

It's a temp folder used by Outlook. Do you have admin rights on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of Outlook. `C:/Documents and Settings/MyUserName/Local Settings/Temporary Internet Files/OLK5F`. This is probably where you'll find it... Outlook uses it to temporarily download mail/attachments to. If found anywhere else, you might be infected and you should cinsider cleaning up and scanning your system.